# Saving form data of forms modified with form_alter hook

Tags: forms

I understand how to add stuff like checkboxes and fieldsets to existing forms (e.g. the form displayed on the node edit page) using _form_alter. But what I don't understand is how to collect the input and store it in a database table of my choosing (ideally with db_insert). Let's say I've added a checkbox to the fieldsets at the bottom of article_node_form (the form which appears when editing content type article):

```
$form["Email Notifications"] = array(
    '#type' => 'fieldset',
    '#title' => 'Email Notifications',
    '#collapsible' => 'true',
    '#group' => 'additional_settings',
    '#required' => FALSE,
    'email_notify' => array (
        '#type' => 'checkbox',
        '#title' => 'Notify users of changes to this page',
        '#default_value' => 0,
        '#required' => FALSE,
)
```

How do I collect this data an store it in a database?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly like you alter a form to add custom fields, you alter it to add custom validation and submit handlers.

It should be:

```
$form['#validate][] = 'custom_validate';
$form['#submit'][] = 'custom_submit';
```

use those function to control the additional user input and store them later.

Comment: how would I name my submission handler in my module, supposing my module is called "my_module," the form has the id of "the_form" and the custom submit field is "custom_submit"? It's information like this I can't find anywhere. it seems nothing is ever explicit in the drupal documentation...

Comment: Well, basically, choose the name you want, as long as is not in use... that means it's considered best practice for your module to use name like mymodule_anynameilike. However, i wouldn't call a field "custom_submit", in your case i would call it "email_notification", because it's another best practice to use names that are... self-describing.

Comment: Think about it, you try to alter a form, and you find a field called "custom_submit". And you'll be like: what the hell is this?

Comment: hmm, well the problem I am running into now is that I get an infinite recursion when I try to access $form["Email Notifications"]["email_notify"] in the submission handler. Any ideas? I just want to be able to see if the checkbox is checked within my module.

Comment: I'm an idiot. Just needed to do: $form["Email Notifications"]["email_notify"]['#value']